# I have this error in R Error in Genpro(): could not find function "Genpro"

Tags: r

1.this my code
2.error can't found Genpro() function
3.this code implement with Google Collab
4.this is all the code for cleaning understand
5.also when i put# in front of GenPro the code is implemented and when i clear # the code implement even RAM is full and crash my session

```
GenPro()
input.data.dir = "/content/chr177.txt"    
output.data.dir = "/content/chr177.csv"        
GenPro <- function(input.data = input.data.dir, output.file = output.data.dir){
   data = read.table(input.data, sep="\t")
   print (data)
   ASCII_Q = c('!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I") 

   num = nrow(data)/4
   idx_1 = c(0:300000) * 4 + 2
   seq = data[idx_1,1]
   idx_2 = c(1:300000) * 4
   qua = data[idx_2,1]
   seq = as.matrix(seq)
   qua = as.matrix(qua)
   rm(data)


  ###---------------------------------------- Parallel computing
  fun <- function(x){
   library(stringr)
   seq_line = str_split(seq[x,],"")
   seq_line = seq_line[[1]][-1]
   qua_line = str_split(qua[x,],"")
   qua_line = qua_line[[1]][-1]
   a.Q = matrix(0, length(seq_line), length(ASCII_Q))
   t.Q = matrix(0, length(seq_line), length(ASCII_Q))
   g.Q = matrix(0, length(seq_line), length(ASCII_Q))
   c.Q = matrix(0, length(seq_line), length(ASCII_Q))   
   for(i in 1:length(seq_line)){
      if(seq_line[i] == "A"){
         idx = which(ASCII_Q == qua_line[i])
         a.Q[i,idx] = 1
      }
      if(seq_line[i] == "T"){
         idx = which(ASCII_Q == qua_line[i])
         t.Q[i,idx] = 1
      }
      if(seq_line[i] == "G"){
         idx = which(ASCII_Q == qua_line[i])
         g.Q[i,idx] = 1
      }
      if(seq_line[i] == "C"){
         idx = which(ASCII_Q == qua_line[i])
         c.Q[i,idx] = 1
      }
   }
   Q.matrix_line = rbind(a.Q,t.Q,g.Q,c.Q)
   return (Q.matrix_line)
  }
  
  library(foreach)
  library(doParallel)
  cl <- makeCluster(8)            # Number of CPUs
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  Q.matrix <- foreach(x=1:(nrow(seq)-1),.combine='+') %dopar% fun(x)
  stopCluster(cl)

  ##------------------------------------------------------------ probability
  Q.matrix.p = Q.matrix
  for(i in 1:nrow(Q.matrix.p)){
     Q.matrix.p[i,] = Q.matrix.p[i,]/sum(Q.matrix.p[i,]) 
  }
  write.table(Q.matrix.p,file=out.file,row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=F,sep="\t")
}
```

Comment: you seem to call the function `GenPro()` before it is defined. R is not a declarative programming language (although perhaps Google Collab implements this??). Try calling the function after it has been defined.

Comment: ps yor probably want to think about returning something from the function and/or not having `rm` as the final command

Comment: I trying calling the function after it has been defined but not work the implement correctly but there are no output. Also i don't understand this point "ps yor probably want to think about returning something from the function and/or not having rm as the final command " i new in this language please can you explain with coding

Comment: The final line in `GenPro()` is `rm(data)` and so the function returns `NULL`. You should `return` something as you do in `fun()`, or else remove the `rm(data)` line in which case it will return `qua` invisibly.